# STR_TO_DATE MySQL swaps Month/Day values

Tags: php, mysql, date

GD All,

When using PHP to insert my data into a MySQL database I pass values using POST method to the script.

using the STR_TO_DATE function in an attempt to get the proper date inserted into the date field in MySQL

However, despite using same format to pass to STR_TO_DATE function (dteReportDate=14-10-2014) the MySQL function apparently swaps the month and day values when monthvalue <= 12 ?

So, if I input 14-10-2014 into the import PHP it correctly reads in the table as 2014-10-14 if I input 09-10-2014 in exactly same routine it is inserted in table as 2014-09-10 ??

How can I correct this in the PHP script or anywhere else ?

I've tried several options:
-changing input to STR_TO_DATE function to be in a avriety of formats (YYYY/MM/DD, dd-mm-yyyy etc.etc. error stays the same
-changing the input data to a string directly for input:
i.e. instead of using

```
    INSERT INTO tbl ('date') VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(dateString,'%Y/%m/%d')
```

You would use

```
    INSERT INTO tbl ('date') VALUES (dateString)
```

Where datestring would be correctly formatted "yyyy-mm-dd" as per MySQL default.
(Doesn't work either)

So how to script it properly so that my input string is correctly translated into date format in MySQL ??

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Accepted date format in **SQL** database is `Y-m-d` (you'll find different date format from [PHP date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

If data is from a *submitted form*:

```
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["date"]));
```

If the date you want to insert is *today and static*:

```
$date=date('Y-m-d');
```

And your query would go like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl ('date') VALUES ('$date')
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the PHP inbuilt funciton:

```
$datevar=   date_create_from_format();
```

Afterwards you can use the the $date varible to post with format funciton.

```
$datevar->format()
```

Answer (score 0):

GD All,

Many thanks for your replies, the error ocurred in an earlier stage in the process.

The STR_TO_DATE was not the issue, it was the data being passed that was faulty.

Thanks for responses !